# I end up studying english VS. I end up to study English

Tags: grammar

What is the difference in meaning between these: "I end up studying English" and "I end up to study English".

Comment: You might be interested in the site for [ell.se].

Answer (score 3):

The first is grammatical, the second isn't.

Comment: 'End up' is a multi-word verb taking an -ing form catenation. 'Start off' behaves similarly, but 'start' can catenate with both -ing forms and to-infinitives. Confusing!

Comment: Ah, you say "catenation", I say "[complement](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/complements.pdf)". Thanks, @Edwin. Tuning.

Comment: @John Lawler: I use the term the way I believe Cobuild does, simply for the overt rather than deeper structures. Cobuild analyses 'verb + -ing form' catenations into three different but similar-appearing structures (and I think they still miss one).

Comment: That's why I prefer McCawley. There are a lot of constructions that wind up with a verb + -ing form, from different sources.